# Creating array of points in C and C++

Tags: c++, c, arrays, struct

There are different ways to reach the same end but this is basically what I am trying to do:

```
typedef struct point_t {
    unsigned int x;
    unsigned int y
} point_t;
```

`point_t points[64] = { {23, 67}, {123, 9}, {55, 0} ... }`

I just want to create a constant array of xy coordinates and read them like this:

```
i = points[0].x
j = points[0].y
```

Is this valid in C and C++?

Comment: Have you tried to actually compile it?

Comment: And do you really need code that compiles as C *and* C++?

Comment: Not sure if applicable, but in case you aim to do heavy computations, you might want to consider [structures of arrays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AOS_and_SOA) instead.

Answer (score 1):

You got a syntax error when declaring your structure, you're missing a semicolon after `unsigned int y`, in any case, the best way to check if it's valid or not is using the c/c++ compiler, for instance, try to compile&run this one:

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct point_t {
    unsigned int x;
    unsigned int y;
} point_t;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    point_t points[64] = {{23, 67}, {123, 9}, {55, 0}};

    for (int i = 0; i < 64; i++) {
        printf("%d %d\n", points[i].x, points[i].y);
    }
}
```

You should see how you've filled up the 3 first points and the rest of your array of structures will be filled up by 0s.

Comment: `printf("%d %d\n", points[i]);` will not work use `printf("%d %d\n", points[i].x, points[i].y);`

Comment: @kaldoran It was working with vs2015 compiler, anyway, editing